# Explicitly illegal character sequence in python code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an UTF-8 input file which regularly contains an illegal character sequence. Since it only appears to be that specific sequence, I want to replace it with its proper equivalent in my Python script.

This should be simple, I thought:

`value = value.replace('\xE2\x80\x3f', u'”'.encode('utf8'))`

However, the script doesn't run - instead, it throws me an error:

`SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file script.py on line 10, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details`

Is there an encoding that allows me to encode any character into a string literal, essentially telling Python to shut up and let me use whatever invalid character I want?

(Note: I am using Python 2.7)

Comment: Does it works with a `# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-` at the top of the python script  ?

Comment: Interestingly, that appears to fix the error in my script. But why does it work, and would it work for any literally encoded character sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

value = "What an amazing string \xE2\x80\x3f !!"

value = value.replace('\xE2\x80\x3f', u'”'.encode('utf8'))

print value
```

The reason this is working is because Python2 interpreter read the input script file as an ASCII file, and doesn't decode UTF-8 characters. Because you write an explicit UTF-8 character into the file (i.e. `”`), you need to tell the interpreter that he has to read the input script file as an UTF-8 file, and not as an ASCII file.

See also the [PEP0263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) about source code encodings

Comment: Now that I see this, I notice that I misinterpreted the error. I thought it was the \xE2 literal causing the issue, without thinking about the UTF-8 character - which also has its first byte encoded as \xE2.